# IE 6-8 fix for this function

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-6

I am working on a small function and it works fine in all browsers, however, in IE6 thru 8 the tags act funny. For instance if you click on Bold you will have `<b></b>`, then if you click on Bold the second time, instead of having another `<b></b>` you'll have `<b></b><b><b></b></b><b></b>`. Not sure why it's doing that.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T2Q89/26/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#btnedit-bold').on("click",function(e) {
    wrapText('b');
});

$('#btnedit-italic').on("click",function(e) {
    wrapText('i');
});

$('#btnedit-underline').on("click",function(e) {
    wrapText('u');
});

$('#btnedit-delete').on("click",function(e) {
    wrapText('del');
});

$('#btnedit-link').on("click",function(e) {
    var textArea = $('.area'),
        len = textArea.val().length,
        start = textArea[0].selectionStart,
        end = textArea[0].selectionEnd,
        selectedText = textArea.val().substring(start, end);
    $('#btnedit-title').val(selectedText);
    $('#btnedit-url').val('http://');
    $('#prompt').show();
});

$('#btnedit-ok').on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#prompt').hide();
    replacement = '<a title="'+$('#btnedit-title').val()+'" href="'+$('#btnedit-url').val()+'" rel="external">' + $('#btnedit-title').val() + '</a>';
    wrapLink(replacement);
}); 

$('#btnedit-cancel').on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#prompt').hide();
}); 
});

function wrapLink(link) {
var textArea = $('.area'),
    len = textArea.val().length,
    start = textArea[0].selectionStart,
    end = textArea[0].selectionEnd,
    selectedText = textArea.val().substring(start, end);
textArea.val(textArea.val().substring(0, start) + link + textArea.val().substring(end, len));
$('.area').keyup();
}


function wrapText(tag) {
var textArea = $('.area'),
    len = textArea.val().length,
    start = textArea[0].selectionStart,
    end = textArea[0].selectionEnd,
    selectedText = textArea.val().substring(start, end),
    replacement = '<' + tag + '>' + selectedText + '</' + tag + '>';
textArea.val(textArea.val().substring(0, start) + replacement +   textArea.val().substring(end, len));
$('.area').keyup();
}

$(function() {  
$('.area').keyup(function(){                    
    var value = $(this).val();
    var contentAttr = $(this).attr( 'name' );
    $( '.' + contentAttr + '' ).html(value);
})
});
```

Comment: In markdown the ` char is good for quoting html.

Comment: Is this what's causing the issue? Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: No. In the body of your question, you wrote some html tags... however, unless you surround them with ` quotes, they won't render in the final output because they'll either be stripped if they're not whitelisted, or rendered as HTML in the document... e.g. your `<b>` tags were not visible in the initial revision of your question.

Comment: Oh, sorry, yes, the code somehow got cut out. I did put the entire jquery code in now.

Comment: Seriously.... I can't even view your fiddle in IE8 because jsfiddle doesn't support IE8. At this point no one should support IE8. as of Jan 12. Microsoft won't even support IE8 much less IE6 and 7. If your app is working in IE9-11 count yourself lucky and move on.

Comment: I realize jsfiddle isn't working in those browsers, but I am able to test that script on my site and the fact remains that in IE6-8 it's doing some weird stuff with the tags. I had a solution to something similar a couple years ago (happened to find online) but I fail to remember what it was.

Comment: In javascript the IE6-8 fix would look something like:

`var element = document.getElementByClassName( 'area' );
if( document.selection ){
var range = document.selection.createRange();
var stored_range = range.duplicate();
stored_range.moveToElementText( element );
stored_range.setEndPoint( 'EndToEnd', range );
element.selectionStart = stored_range.text.length - range.text.length;
element.selectionEnd = element.selectionStart + range.text.length;
}`

Now how do I implement something similar in that particular jquery code?

Comment: I am close to figuring this out. This took care of the issue, but it now places the cursor in front of a new set of tags (ie <b></b>). I need it to be placed at the end. What needs to be done? I tried a couple things nothing worked.

`var textArea = $('.area').get(0);
    var elemLen = textArea.value.length;
    textArea.selectionStart = elemLen;
    textArea.selectionEnd = elemLen;
    textArea.focus();`

Comment: Can't edit my last comment. I need to place the cursor **between** the tags.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem here is that old IE versions don't support the `.selectionStart` and `.selectionEnd` properties properly.

So you're going to need to do something alternative. Since you're already using jQuery, my first suggestion is to try the [jQuery FieldSelection library](https://github.com/localhost/jquery-fieldselection).

However note that I haven't used this library in *ages* (partly because it's not an area of functionality I've needed to write for in a while, but mostly because I don't have to support IE6-8 and more).

I see on the github page that it hasn't been updated in a number of years and claims to be compatible with jQuery 1.0.2, so I suspect there's a good chance that it won't work out of the box. However it's code is easy to read and does show how to do text selection in old IE, so worst case if it doesn't work, you could at least crib the technique from it.